# Can we remove click event without calling it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, dojo

I am having problem in overriding the pagination code given by grid. What I need to do is kind of hack the pagination given by my grid.

We are having a lot of records. So, what we are doing we are loading records to a threshold limit.

So, lets assume the threshold limit is 50 and page size is 10 so there will be 5 pages. So, when user comes to 5th page next button provided by the grid will be disabled. 
So, what we need to do we need to make it enable and if user clicks on it I need make ajax call and load another 50 records(threshold limit) in the grid. 
After that I need to disable this event so that next time user clicks it should not do the make ajax call and it should work like previously (by going from 1st page to 2nd page and so on)

All the above things mentioned I am able to do. But here problem comes when user goes to 5th page and go back to some other page let say 3 without clicking next button. Now, after going to 3rd page
when user clicks on the next page button it is making ajax call as I have make the button enable when user comes to 5th page and provided a click event to it. 
So even if I provide a condition to run only on when grid current page is 5 then also it is running because after going to 5th page I will make button enable and bind and event. So, as I provided the event it will run without even specifying the condition.
How do I make the click event work as default and only when the user is at 5 it will make the ajax call.

This is my code -

```
    ///grid Current page will tell us which page we are in the grid. 
if(gridCurrentPage==5){
              query(".dojoxGridWardButton").forEach(function(element) {
                    query(".dojoxGridnextPageBtnDisable").replaceClass("dojoxGridnextPageBtn", "dojoxGridnextPageBtnDisable");
                    query(".dojoxGridlastPageBtnDisable").replaceClass("dojoxGridlastPageBtn", "dojoxGridlastPageBtnDisable");
                }); 
              callNextButton(gridCurrentPage)
              }
```

And this is the function.

```
function callNextButton(gridCurrentPage) {


    var target = dojo.query(".dojoxGridnextPageBtn");


    var signal = on(target, "click", function(event){  ///Adding click event


    if (gridCurrentPage ==5 ) {

    var deferred = new dojo.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.callback({
            called: true
        })
    }, 2000);
    if (checking some conditions) {

            ////////doing Ajax call
            deferred.then(function() {
                //calling a callback
            })
        },
    error: function(e) {}
    };
    })


    signal.remove();                        //Removing click event
}
```

Note : My grid is enhanced grid which is part of dojo toolkit. But probably its a design issue so, any comments/advices are welcome.

I really need an advice here. Please anyone can find the problem where it is it will be reqlly helpful.

Comment: up to you fourth tab add class `next` to your button, then add `finish` on 5th tab, and call ajax on `.finish` class

Comment: sorry I dont understand. Anyway I am calling on basis of class only. I will first make button enable by changing class then calling click event on class and button class is different from tab class also

Comment: add a specific class to your button when user reached to 5th tab, and perform ajax on that specific class click event

Comment: so I will remove class when I am on some other page but will add when I am on the last page...

Comment: yeah, you got my point